# Using TestOn in flutter test

Tags: android, flutter

I am trying to create unit tests on flutter. A dynamic library is loaded only if the platform is Android. Thus, I have written @TestOn('android') on top of the testing file. However, in that case, I am getting "No tests match regular expression" error and no test was running. Without that statement, it executes the code until it hits that dynamic library usage. Here is how it loads. Do I miss a configuration?

```
DynamicLibrary tflitelib = () {
  if (Platform.isAndroid) {
    return DynamicLibrary.open('libtensorflowlite_c.so');
  } else if (Platform.isIOS) {
    return DynamicLibrary.process();
  }
}();
```

Answer (score 0):

At least I have found an alternative that works:
`flutter run -d emulator test/testfile.dart`